# streaming video from cordova camera using wowza streaming services

Tags: android, cordova, video, cordova-plugins, wowza

I am new to **Ionic and Cordova**. I want to do recording from one device & watching from another devise.

I am using this org.apache.cordova.camera plugin for camera and media-capture for capturing videos.

I wanted to integrate wowza. So the question is how cordova supports Wowza and how to do(code) it using Ionic + Cordova.

Thanks for help

Comment: any help plzzz... may I know why this question got down rating?